# Why does $Q(C)=\int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\cdots\int_0^{x_3}\int_0^{x_2} dx_1\,dx_2\cdots dx_{n-1}\,dx_n$?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I don't understand this part of the book about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoFDo.jpg) example in the probability theory book:

> Let $C$ be a set in $n$-dimensional space and let
> $$Q(C)=\int_C dx_1\,dx_2\cdots dx_n.$$
>
> If $C=\left\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n): 0\le x_1\le x_2\le \cdots \le x_n\le 1\right\},$ then
>
> \begin{align}
> Q(C)&=\int_0^1\int_0^{x_n}\cdots\int_0^{x_3}\int_0^{x_2} dx_1\,dx_2\cdots dx_{n-1}\,dx_n
> \\&=\frac1{n!}\,,
> \end{align}
> where $n!=n(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot2\cdot 1$.

I don't understand in the $Q(C)$ part. Why is the integral from $x_n$ to $0$ written first, and why is it $dx_1\, dx_2\cdots dx_{n-1} \,dx_n$ ?

Comment: Take the case where n=3, and try draw a picture of the integral

Comment: $x_n$ goes from $0$ to $1$; for fixed $x_n$, $x_{n-1}$ goes from $0$ to $x_n$; for fixed $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$, $x_{n-2}$ goes from $0$ to $x_{n-1}$; etc. This is how to algebraically read multiple integral notation: the $k$th integral from the left has $k-1$ variables held fixed. A picture in low dimension will help also.

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, please try to typeset math using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) whenever possible.

Comment: I don't understand why the end result is 1/n!. I can't see where it comes from.